# Audio file doesn't play (Twilio trial account)

Tags: twilio, voice, ivr

I am using a trial account to test building a simple voice experience where when someone calls the number they hear a "Say" message and then a "Play" message is heard.

I can't get the "Play" message to play. I get an error message.

I have tried both MP3 and Wav file formats and tried hosting the file initially on DropBox and now on AWS S3?

Any ideas? Is it because I am using a trial account? I would like to test the functionality before committing to buying a number and a monthly plan.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. The answer is to use a .wav file and store it as a Twilio public asset - don't use a third party host. Also I'm not sure why they use .mp3 in their examples, their documentation when you finally find it says they don't support .mp3